# Modify the authors field of article class (authblk package)

Tags: article, french, authblk

I am puzzling how I can modify the author field in article class when using the authblk package. I am writing an article in French. The following code

```
\documentclass[french,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\clubpenalty = 10000
\widowpenalty = 10000


\usepackage{graphicx,bm,url, amsfonts, latexsym, verbatim, xspace, setspace,mathrsfs,marvosym,wasysym,amsmath, amssymb}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}


\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*,itemsep=1pt,topsep=1pt}
%\setlist[description]{leftmargin=*,itemsep=1pt,topsep=1pt}
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=*,itemsep=1pt,topsep=1pt}


\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=red,
    urlcolor=blue,
    pdftitle={article},
    pdfauthor={DSA}]{hyperref}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Mots clés ---}} #1}

\providecommand{\thematic}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Thématique ---}} #1}

\usepackage{authblk}

\newcommand{\M}{{\it Mathematica}}


\begin{document}

\title{Une bonne publication}
\author[,1]{Dimitrios\thanks{\texttt{\url{dimitrios.@X.fr}}}}
\author[,1]{Panos\thanks{ \texttt{\url{panos@Y.fr}}}}
\author[,1]{Thanos\thanks{Corresponding author: 
\texttt{\url{thanos@Z.fr}}}}
\affil[1]{Université de nulle parte, Terre, Galaxie}

\date{}

\clearpage\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}

\blindtext


\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

produces (partial snapshot)

[image]

I want the list of authors appear with the French word *et* instead of *and*. That is,

> Dimitrios, Panos et Thanos

Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the package provides the `\Authand` and `\Authands` commands which you can redefine as you see fit:

```
\usepackage{authblk}
\renewcommand\Authand{ et }
\renewcommand\Authands{, et }
```

Output:

[image: output]

Refer to section 4 of the `authblk` documentation for furter details.